# Spring: Using @EntityScan disables automatic entity discovery

Tags: java, spring

I have two spring projects:

- core
- worker

`core` is used as a maven dependency in `worker`. Its classes contain several `@Autowired` fields.

In order to have these fields be correctly instantiated in `worker`, I added this config class to `core`:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example.core")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.core.repo")
@EntityScan("com.example.core.entities")
public class CoreSharedConfig {}
```

This config is then `@Import`ed in the main application class of `worker`

This works, however this causes all the repos and entities defined in `worker` to not instantiate, unless I add a second config to `worker` containing this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.worker.repo")
@EntityScan("com.example.worker.entities")
public class WorkerRepoScanConfig {
}
```

If I remove either `@EnableJpaRepositories` or `@EntityScan` from the above, then repos in `com.example.worker.repo` and entities in `com.example.worker.entities` fail to be created (even though the current project being run is `worker` and `core` is just a dependency).

What's the issue here? Does using `@EntityScan` or `@EnableJpaRepositories` in `core` mean automatic entity discovery is disabled everywhere else?

Comment: can you please post also the class with `@Import` and also clarify if both projects are spring boot applications ? Also please write more clear what you remove from what project which leads to the result that you mention.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is the class annotated with

> @Import

is **not** annotated with

> @Configuration

and it should for `@Import` to work.